# Find start and end positions/indices of runs/consecutive values

Tags: r, vector, run-length-encoding

Problem: Given an atomic vector, find the start and end indices of runs in the vector.

Example vector with runs:

```
x = rev(rep(6:10, 1:5))
# [1] 10 10 10 10 10  9  9  9  9  8  8  8  7  7  6
```

Output from `rle()`:

```
rle(x)
# Run Length Encoding
#  lengths: int [1:5] 5 4 3 2 1
#  values : int [1:5] 10 9 8 7 6
```

Desired output:

```
#   start end
# 1     1   5
# 2     6   9
# 3    10  12
# 4    13  14
# 5    15  15
```

The base `rle` class doesn't appear to provide this functionality, but the class [`Rle`](http://web.mit.edu/~r/current/arch/i386_linux26/lib/R/library/S4Vectors/html/Rle-class.html) and function [`rle2`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/accelerometry/versions/2.2.5/topics/rle2) do. However, given how minor the functionality is, sticking to base R seems more sensible than installing and loading additional packages.

There are examples of code snippets ([here](https://books.google.com/books?id=grfuq1twFe4C&pg=PA32&lpg=PA32&dq=rle%20starts%20ends%20r&source=bl&ots=ms2GT5ONRB&sig=8c524ncWroPQrCQonrpkoghp_wc&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiEqM__j-PTAhVKwVQKHVNlAcEQ6AEITTAH#v=onepage&q=rle%20starts%20ends%20r&f=false), [here](http://masterr.org/r/how-to-find-consecutive-repeats-in-r/) and [on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41759473/locate-start-and-end-of-consecutive-values-below-threshold)) which solve the slightly different problem of finding start and end indices for runs which satisfy some condition. I wanted something that would be more general, could be performed in one line, and didn't involve the assignment of temporary variables or values.

Answering my own question because I was frustrated by the lack of search results. I hope this helps somebody!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Core logic:

```
# Example vector and rle object
x = rev(rep(6:10, 1:5))
rle_x = rle(x)

# Compute endpoints of run
end = cumsum(rle_x$lengths)
start = c(1, lag(end)[-1] + 1)

# Display results
data.frame(start, end)
#   start end
# 1     1   5
# 2     6   9
# 3    10  12
# 4    13  14
# 5    15  15
```

Tidyverse/`dplyr` way (data frame-centric):

```
library(dplyr)

rle(x) %>%
  unclass() %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  mutate(end = cumsum(lengths),
         start = c(1, dplyr::lag(end)[-1] + 1)) %>%
  magrittr::extract(c(1,2,4,3)) # To re-order start before end for display
```

Because the `start` and `end` vectors are the same length as the `values` component of the `rle` object, solving the related problem of identifying endpoints for runs meeting some condition is straightforward: `filter` or subset the `start` and `end` vectors using the condition on the run values.

Comment: Hi @Clara! I have some problems running your code. In your first solution, do you mean `dplyr::lag`? In your second solution, do mean `select` instead of `extract` (from `tidyr`?) ? Cheers

Comment: If you want to keep the first solution in `base`, you may use `head(end, -1)` instead of `lag`.

Comment: @Henrik Good question! I meant `stats::lag` (I also recently ran into a problem with namespace collision between `dplyr` and `stats` on `lag`, so understand why you would ask!). For `extract`, I mean `magrittr::extract`, which is a forward pipe-friendly function for the `[` operator.

Thank you for calling those ambiguities out, I hadn't realized at the time what I was doing!

Comment: Thanks for your response @Clara! With `stats::lag` I get a different result than what you show. `(start <- c(1, stats::lag(end)[-1] + 1))`; `[1]  1 10 13 15 16`. `dplyr::lag` gives the result you show though: `(start <- c(1, dplyr::lag(end)[-1] + 1))`; `[1]  1  6 10 13 15`. Cheers

Comment: Also without `lag`: `start <- end - rle_x$lengths + 1`

Answer (score 10):

A `data.table` possibility, where `.I` and `.N` are used to pick relevant indices, per group defined by `rleid` runs.

```
library(data.table)
data.table(x)[ , .(start = .I[1], end = .I[.N]), by = rleid(x)][, rleid := NULL][]
#    start end
# 1:     1   5
# 2:     6   9
# 3:    10  12
# 4:    13  14
# 5:    15  15
```