# Restructure data based on row numbers in R

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, tidyverse, tidyr

I am having troubles restructuring the data as I need to.
My df looks like this:

```
id <- (1:20)
author <- c("A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","A","A","A","B","B","B","B"
            ,"B","B","B","A","A")
df <- data.frame(id, author)

> print(df)

   id author
1   1      A
2   2      A
3   3      A
4   4      A
5   5      A
6   6      B
7   7      B
8   8      B
9   9      A
10 10      A
11 11      A
12 12      B
13 13      B
14 14      B
15 15      B
16 16      B
17 17      B
18 18      B
19 19      A
20 20      A
```

And I'm trying to get a data structure where the columns are the authors and the rwos indicate the first and last id values of each sequence of A or B values. So in this case the first row with author A is id = 1, and the last one of that series is id 5, and so forth.
Something like this:

```
A <- c(1, 5, 9, 11, 19,20)
B <- c(6, 8, 12, 18, NA, NA)
df.desired <- data.frame(A, B)
print(df.desired)
   A  B
1  1  6
2  5  8
3  9 12
4 11 18
5 19 NA
6 20 NA
```

Any ideas?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Related: [Find start and end positions/indices of runs/consecutive values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43875716/find-start-and-end-positions-indices-of-runs-consecutive-values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a base R option

```
z <- rle(df$author)
lst <- split(df,findInterval(1:nrow(df),cumsum(z$lengths), left.open = TRUE))
u <- lapply(lst,function(v) range(v$id))
idx <- split(seq_along(z$values),z$values)
x <- lapply(idx,function(v) unlist(u[v],use.names = FALSE))
df.desired <- as.data.frame(lapply(x,`length<-`,max(lengths(x))))
```

which gives

```
> df.desired
   A  B
1  1  6
2  5  8
3  9 12
4 11 18
5 19 NA
6 20 NA
```

Answer (score 3):

We can create groups using `data.table` `rleid`, select 1st and last row in each group and get data in wide format.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(grp = data.table::rleid(author)) %>%
  slice(1L, n()) %>%
  group_by(author) %>%
  mutate(grp = row_number()) %>%
  tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = author, values_from = id) %>%
  select(-grp)

# A tibble: 6 x 2
#      A     B
#  <int> <int>
#1     1     6
#2     5     8
#3     9    12
#4    11    18
#5    19    NA
#6    20    NA
```

---

For the updated request in comments we can do :

```
df %>%
  group_by(grp = data.table::rleid(author)) %>%
  slice(1L, n()) %>%
  mutate(author = row_number()) %>%
  tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = row, values_from = id) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  select(-grp)

# A tibble: 5 x 2
#    `1`   `2`
#  <int> <int>
#1     1     5
#2     6     8
#3     9    11
#4    12    18
#5    19    20
```

Comment: Great, thanks! can I make a follow up q? What if I wanted a row to specify a sequence by each author?
So in this case X1 <- (1,6,9,12,19) and X2 <- (5,8,11,18,20), df <- data.frame(X1, X2).
Thanks again!

Comment: @AntVal You can use `as.data.frame(do.call(rbind,u))` with `u` in my code to generate that `df`

Comment: @AntVal That is a small change in the original answer. Please see updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

An option using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
dcast(
    setDT(df)[, ri := rleid(author)][, id[c(1L, .N)], .(author, ri)],
    rowid(author) ~ author, value.var="V1")
```

output:

```
   author  A  B
1:      1  1  6
2:      2  5  8
3:      3  9 12
4:      4 11 18
5:      5 19 NA
6:      6 20 NA
```

If there is a possibility of an author having a single row, you will need `unique(c(1L, .N))`