# Extract all subsets in vector where elements are above a given threshold

Tags: r, vector, subset

I would like to know if there is an R way (one liner) to extract the coordinates of all subsets of a vector that are above a given threshold.
Suppose I have the following data:

```
v =  c(3.48, 2.59, 1.73, 0.91, 0.13, -0.63, -1.34, -2.03, -2.67, -3.28, -3.04, -2.15, -1.20, -0.19, 0.84, 1.86, 2.84, 3.77, 4.60, 5.31, 4.16, 2.87, 1.89, 0.51, 0.23, 0.78, 1.34, 2.63, 1.72, 0.62, 0.98, 1.45)
```

and let's say I have `threshold = 0.7`. The desired output would be:

```
left    right
1       4
15      23
26      29
31      32
```

I can in principle write a `while` loop or some sort, subsetting `v` and juggling with `left` and `right` coordinates of these regions, something like:

```
left = which(subset >= threshold)[1] + right
right = which(subset[left:length(subset)] < threshold)[1] - 1 # -1 to get the last element above the threshold

subset = v[(right + 1):length(v)]
```

(not tested), but I am sure there is an R way that i can't seem to remember.

I had a look [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/invctr/vignettes/insiders.html) but it's not really what I am after. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you just interested in the positions of elements <0.7 or do you want consecutive intervals?

Comment: consecutive intervals. like [1,4], [15,23], etc..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `rle()` to find the runs of values that exceed your threshhold. When you can turn that into your desired format

```
rle(v>.7) |>
  with(
    data.frame(start=1, end=cumsum(lengths)) |> 
      transform(start=c(1, head(end, -1) + 1)) |> 
      subset(values)
  )
```

And that returns

```
  start end
1     1   4
3    15  23
5    26  29
7    31  32
```

This is nearly identical to [this existing question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43875716/find-start-and-end-positions-indices-of-runs-consecutive-values) with the main difference of using `rle()` on your Boolean condition and then subsetting to only the TRUE values.

Answer (score 1):

Same solution but using data.table

```
v =  c(3.48, 2.59, 1.73, 0.91, 0.13, -0.63, -1.34, -2.03, -2.67, -3.28, -3.04, -2.15, -1.20, -0.19, 0.84, 1.86, 2.84, 3.77, 4.60, 5.31, 4.16, 2.87, 1.89, 0.51, 0.23, 0.78, 1.34, 2.63, 1.72, 0.62, 0.98, 1.45)

data.table(v)[, .(start = .I[1], end = .I[.N], keep = unique(v > 0.7)), by = rleid(v > 0.7)][keep == T, .(start, end)]

#    start end
# 1:     1   4
# 2:    15  23
# 3:    26  29
# 4:    31  32
```